# Android preserve view height between views with layout_height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have a `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation with many child views inside it. Each one of these child views have a `layout_weight` parameter which determines its height depending on screen size. There is one of this child views, which is between the other child views, that I want to preserve a constant height for it.

The question is: ¿How can I set a constant height for this target child view without affecting heights of the child views above and below this target view across screen sizes?

Hope I get fully understood for what I want to do.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what you exactly want ??

as i understood, do you want same height-size childs in parent layout???

can you please explain?

can you add image you want?

Answer (score 0):

A1:
If ChildView 1 and 3 keeps original height, total height (ChildView 1 - 3) will change.
So if you set parent LinearLayout height as constant (match_parent etc.), ChildView 1 and 3 will change there height.
If you set layout_height="wrap_content" and minHeight="300dp"(for example) to LinearLayout, ChildView 1 and 3 will not shrink there height.

```
LinearLayout(vertical)

---
ChildView 1
(height set by weight)

---
ChildView 2
(constant height)
layout_height="20dp"

---
ChildView 3
(height set by weight)

---
Blank space here

---
```

---

A2:
Wrap ChildView 2 with LinearLayout(vertical)

```
LinearLayout 1 (vertical)

---
ChildView 1
(height set by weight)

---
LinearLayout 2
(height set by weight)
layout_weight="1"

    ChildView 2
    (constant height)
    layout_height="20dp"

    Blank space here
    (height will be (LinearLayout 2 height) - (ChildView2 height))

---
ChildView 3
(height set by weight)

---
```